# Where are RPM postinstall scripts located?

Tags: shell-script, rpm

I have found a bug in an RPM that I have been provided.

```
rpm -qp --scripts foo.rpm > /tmp/badscript

cat /tmp/badscript
postinstall scriptlet (using /bin/sh):
...
if [ 'some bug' == true ]....
```

I have access to the source code and the spec files, but I am unable to find which file is the postinstall scriptlet.

Is it possible for me to fix this bug? If so where do I find the script?

I assumed it would be in buildutils/rpmbuild/SPEC, yet when I grep the entire source code, I can't find the string that contains the bug.

Comment: Could you change your example with the actual code? Is it really called `basdscript` and `postinstall scriptlet` and `'some bug'`? What rpm is this? How can we help with the information provided?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are in the spec file itself. See

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#_syntax

In your case search for a `%post` section.